# getting error in converting string to JSON in my application

Tags: java, android, json

in my application, I am getting a string which I want to convert to JSON
to do this, I use the following :

```
    JsonParser gsonTest = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject toto= new 
    JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonObject();
    testhash = toto.get("access_token").getAsString();
```

but i get the following error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: 
    {
        "access_token": "NmUxMjdjYjllZWNhZDBhNjNhMGJmYzE0YWE1YjIzOTM2ODkwMGI3ZmMyZDRmNDJhMGRkNGNiM2U4N2FkZTk4Yg",
        "expires_in": 3600,
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "scope": null,
        "refresh_token": "MDZkYWFlOGEwN2M0MGE1MDFmZmRhYmVlOGE0NTllMWY0NTBlY2VhZmJhYTJlM2RkM2NkNjhlZjk3M2E5ZDQxMQ",
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "serverPath": "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SupDocAPI/Storage",
            "username": "toto",
            "defaultFolder": 2,
            "email": "toto@gmail.com"
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your  response json format .

Comment: Preferably the original, unescaped JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Response not a proper JSON format. It would be like this  `{"access_token":"NmUxMjdjYjllZWNhZDBhNjNh"}`. Remove the back slash "\" from JSON response.

Comment: Java escapes " characters when printing them to console, so that doesn't prevent the JSON from being invalid.

Answer (score 0):

JSON String is valid but JSON Data is not accurate, you have to remove all `escape char back slash "\"` to get the real data:

```
{
    "access_token": "NmUxMjdjYjllZWNhZDBhNjNhMGJmYzE0YWE1YjIzOTM2ODkwMGI3ZmMyZDRmNDJhMGRkNGNiM2U4N2FkZTk4Yg",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": null,
    "refresh_token": "MDZkYWFlOGEwN2M0MGE1MDFmZmRhYmVlOGE0NTllMWY0NTBlY2VhZmJhYTJlM2RkM2NkNjhlZjk3M2E5ZDQxMQ",
    "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "serverPath": "\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/SupDocAPI\/Storage",
        "username": "toto",
        "defaultFolder": 2,
        "email": "toto@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not escaped the characters properly. Try this

```
try {
        response=response.replace("\u0022","\"");
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
        testhash=jsonObject.getString("access_token");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it works but if i use my api with the JSONObject i get :05-14 14:44:10.603 22508-22508/com.supinfo.supfile W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"access_token":"Y2U3NTYxYWJmNmVhMjlhNWYzNWExY2FiMjVkYWE5ZWUzZmFkYWI1ZGZmMWY4ZDQ2YzdhZA","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"bearer","scope":null,"refresh_token":"Mjc0ZTg5YTBhMTE1Y2Q2NmMyNzcwZjJkMjMwNWY4ZWYzMjJjZGNjNjc2Nzc0NmJhNzMwNGVmMmJmMDIwN2E0Yg","user":{"id":3,"serverPath":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/SupDocAPI\/Storage","username":"toto","defaultFolder":2,"email":"toto@gmail.com"}} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I also get this 05-15 07:14:50.137 8992-8992/com.supinfo.supfile I/INFO: "{\u0022access_token\u0022:\u0022MDI3NmFhMjEyYjJhODI0NGE5OWQwMzQ4FlYTA1ZGIzZWU5ZTM0MQ\u0022,\u0022expires_in\u0022:3600,\u0022token_type\u0022:\u0022bearer\u0022,\u0022scope\u0022:null,\u0022refresh_token\u0022:\u0022YTQ0MWJkNWFmNWI5NzQ1OTNjM2U5wZmVlMzVkYmUyMGQ4MTY3OA\u0022,\u0022user\u0022:{\u0022id\u0022:3,\u0022serverPath\u0022:\u0022\\\/Applications\\\/MAMP\\\/htdocs\\\/SupDocAPI\\\/Storage\u0022,\u0022username\u0022:\u0022toto\u0022,\u0022defaultFolder\u0022:2,\u0022email\u0022:\u0022toto@gmail.com\u0022}}"

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the backslashes first:

```
// Replace all \" by "
String json = response.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");


JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject toto= parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
testhash = toto.get("access_token").getAsString();
```